# Can a function in R return two vectors?

Tags: r, function

Can a function in R return not one, but two vectors?

*(I am really beginning with R, so I might be overlooking something simple)*

Comment: See this relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826519/function-returning-more-than-one-value

Comment: As @george-dontas points out, this question/answer should be tagged as duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning multiple objects in an R function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936099/returning-multiple-objects-in-an-r-function)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Return them in a *list*:

```
return(list(v1 = v1, v2 = v2))
```