# Returning multiple objects in an R function

Tags: r, function

How can I return multiple objects in an R function? In Java, I would make a Class, maybe `Person` which has some private variables and encapsulates, maybe, `height`, `age`, etc.

But in R, I need to pass around groups of data. For example, how can I make an R function return both an list of characters and an integer?

Comment: I think maybe its not intuitive to folks coming from other languages, but lists are the way to do this. So you'd have a list containing two elements: a list and a single integer.

Comment: This question is very similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826519/function-returning-more-than-one-value). There are some different answers over there.

Comment: I much prefer the *question title*, *question body text*, and *answers* here than [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826519/function-returning-more-than-one-value) this was closed as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 283, accepted):

Unlike many other languages, R functions don't return multiple objects in the strict sense.  The most general way to handle this is to return a `list` object.  So if you have an integer `foo` and a vector of strings `bar` in your function, you could create a list that combines these items:

```
foo <- 12
bar <- c("a", "b", "e")
newList <- list("integer" = foo, "names" = bar)
```

Then `return` this list.

After calling your function, you can then access each of these with `newList$integer` or `newList$names`.

Other object types might work better for various purposes, but the `list` object is a good way to get started.

Comment: To assign the elements in the returned list at once, look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15140507

Answer (score 37):

Similarly in Java, you can create a S4 class in R that encapsulates your information:

```
setClass(Class="Person",
         representation(
            height="numeric",
            age="numeric"
          )
)
```

Then your function can return an instance of this class:

```
myFunction = function(age=28, height=176){
  return(new("Person",
          age=age,
          height=height))
}
```

and you can access your information:

```
aPerson = myFunction()

aPerson@age
aPerson@height
```

Comment: Just learning here... when would it be useful to return something like `aPerson@age` or `aPerson@height` when you obviously already have defined the age and height with `myFunction = function(age=28, height=176){...`.  I just don't get it (i.e., why this is useful).  So you've instantiated your class, and then you want to know details about the instance.  But since you've instantiated the class, don't you already know these details?

Comment: @warship it is just a dummy example to explain how to return an object. The way I build the object doesn't matter here. We could also have myFunction computing the age and the height from other parameters.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot.  I'm just trying to learn a little bit more about doing OOP in R (S3, S4, etc), and when it would be useful.

Answer (score 24):

Is something along these lines what you are looking for?

```
x1 = function(x){
  mu = mean(x)
  l1 = list(s1=table(x),std=sd(x))
  return(list(l1,mu))
}

library(Ecdat)
data(Fair)
x1(Fair$age)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use super-assignment.

Rather than "<-" type "<<-". The function will recursively and repeatedly search one functional level higher for an object of that name. If it can't find one, it will create one on the global level.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `for()` with `assign()` to create many objects. 
See the example from `assign()`:

```
for(i in 1:6) { #-- Create objects  'r.1', 'r.2', ... 'r.6' --
    nam <- paste("r", i, sep = ".")
    assign(nam, 1:i)
```

Looking the new objects

```
ls(pattern = "^r..$")
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to handle this is to put the information as an attribute on the primary one. I must stress, I really think this is the appropriate thing to do only when the two pieces of information are related such that one has information about the other.

For example, I sometimes stash the name of "crucial variables" or variables that have been significantly modified by storing a list of variable names as an attribute on the data frame:

```
attr(my.DF, 'Modified.Variables') <- DVs.For.Analysis$Names.of.Modified.Vars
return(my.DF)
```

This allows me to store a list of variable names with the data frame itself.