# R- accessing varibales created within a user defined function after end of function

Tags: r

Take a basic function

```
fun<-function(){
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
y<-c(1,2,3,4,5)

t<-x+y
return(t)

}
```

After I have run the function, is there a way I can access any of the variables created within the function. Either by specifying the variable- something like this:

```
fun$y
```

or

```
fun$t
```

or is there some way of asking R to save the variable within the function for use during my current R session (I'm not looking to save it permanently). AKA something along the lines of:

```
fun<-function(){
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
y<-c(1,2,3,4,5)

t<-x+y
Y<-save y for latter use
T<-save T for latter use
return(t)

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a variable outside of its scope.

What you can do is use a list to return multiple values from your function.

Here's a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8936179/1117415).

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something important. But if I were to follow the info in your link and add two lines to the above code    "newList<-list("YY"=y,"XX"=x)" & "return(newList)"- after I execute the function- if I type in newList$XX I get the message "Error:object 'newList' not found.

Comment: @VincentMoriarty Once again, functions don't (in general) have side effects. If your function `return`s something, you have to _assign_ the output of your function to something. i.e. `result <- fun()`.

Comment: You're still trying to access the function's local variable. Use result<-fun() then result$XX.

Comment: That's the ticket! Thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no.

**Yes**, it is technically possible to make assignments to variables outside the scope of your function, so that they are accessible elsewhere. Typically this is done using either `<<-`, which assigns in the global environment if the variable being assigned can't be found, or calling `assign` and specifying an environment directly.

But...

**No**, you should probably **not** be doing this. R is a functional language, which means that it is intended to be used such that its functions do not create side-effects. If you violate this principle too much, you will inevitably run afoul of serious problems that will be difficult, if not impossible to debug.

If you create variables within a function that you will need later, it is considered best practice to return them all in a list, as Benito describes.