# Why doesn't this returning of multiple values of work?

Tags: r

```
return_sum_diff <- function(a,b){return(list(a+b,a-b))}
list[t1,t2] = return_sum_diff(1,2)
```

It fails with the error

> Error in list[t1, t2] <- return_sum_diff(2, 2) : object 't1' not found

I was trying to implement the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936099/returning-multiple-objects-in-an-r-function) for returning multiple arguments.

Comment: I guess in R you cant assign like that. just assign like `a <- return_sum_diff(1,2)`

Comment: What is `t1` and `t2`? What is `list[]`?

Comment: i want t1=a+b and t2=a-b to happen.

Comment: So why do you need `list[t1,t2]` for? It happens without it. Just `return_sum_diff(1,2)` gives you what you want. I'm confused.

Comment: Are you suggesting a solution like a <- return_sum_diff(1,2) and then t1=a[1] and t2=a[2]

Comment: `yourlist <- setNames(return_sum_diff(1,2), c("t1", "t2"))`

Answer (score 1):

I guess in R you cant assign like that. just assign like `a <- return_sum_diff(1,2)` Here a will be a list with two values.

If u want a named list, modify function as follows

```
return_sum_diff <- function(a,b){return(list(t1 = a+b, t2 = a-b))}
```