# How to define a closure?

Tags: r

Here I'm attempting to define a closure that contains a function which can be invoked :

```
myFirstClosure <- function (){

  var1 = 1;

  f1 <- function() {
    var1
  }

}

m <- myFirstClosure()
m.f1()
```

Error is returned : `Error: could not find function "m.f1"`

Why is the inner scoped function `f1` not accessible as I have defined the outer scoped function `myFirstClosure` ?

Update :

Is it meaningless to invoke closures like :

```
myFirstClosure <- function (){

  var1 = 1;
  var2 = 0;

  f1 <- function() {
    var1
  }

  f2 <- function() {
    var2
  }

}
```

As `f1` and `f2` cannot be invoked independently ?

Comment: Regarding your update, take a look at `?environment`. You can place your `var1`, `var2`, `f1` and `f2` inside the same environment.

Comment: With your updates, I'd be tempted to mark as a dupe of [Return more than one object from an R function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8936099/903061).

Comment: @Gregor: I think this question has more to do with how to abuse R to simulate classical OO paradigm. My understanding is that the OP is trying to define a "class" with "member variables" and "member functions". Returning multiple objects is a by-product of this particular solution, but I would argue that's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 6):

`.` is meaningless in R (except for S3 method dispatch, but that's not relevant here), and the fact that the returned function was once called `f1` in the environment of the function that created it is not retained. As soon as you assign `myFirstClosure()` to `m`,

```
m <- myFirstClosure()
```

its name is `m` and nothing else. You can call it with `m()`.

For additional reading, I'd suggest the Functional Programming chapters of [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use that form, `m.f1()` because that's not `R`syntax. You can use a similar form, with environments. Something like the following.

```
myFirstClosure <- function (){
    var1 <- 1
    e <- environment(myFirstClosure)
    e$f1 <- function() {
        var1
    }
    e
}

m <- myFirstClosure()
m$f1()
#[1] 1
```

Note however that `myFirstClosure` would then return an environment, not a closure. This probably defeats your original goal.
See also [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf), section `10.7 Scope`, the `open.account` example for another way of doing something like what you seem to want.

**EDIT.**
To answer to the question's edit by the OP, and repeating the code above a bit, the example above can be extended to any number of functions.

```
myFirstClosure <- function (){
    var1 <- 1
    var2 <- 0
    e <- environment(myFirstClosure)
    e$f1 <- function() {
        var1
    }
    e$f2 <- function() {
        var2
    }
    e
}

m <- myFirstClosure()
m$f1()
#[1] 1

m$f2()
#[1] 0
```

Comment: please see my recent question update, I think your answer is closest to what I'm planing to use.

Answer (score 2):

This achieves the behavior I'm looking for :

```
myFirstClosure <- function() {

  var1 <- 1;
  var2 <- 0;

  list(f1=function() { 
    var1
  },f2=function() { 
    var2
  })
}

m <- myFirstClosure()
m$f1()
m$f2()
```

This aided in finding solution https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-closures-as-objects-in-r/ as well as answers / comments for this question.

Comment: I highly recommend you take a look at the `R6` package.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer here is that you have defined your closure on m itself, and need to simply invoke m

```
myFirstClosure <- function (){

  var1 = 1;

  f1 <- function() {
    var1
  }

}

m <- myFirstClosure()
m()
```

I just ran this and it outputs `1` as you desire.

I am aware that you are hoping to do something slightly different - your code reminds me of the closure-as-module pattern in javascript, where your closure-creating function outputs an object with multiple functions that can be called individually as attributes, all with a closure on variables internal to the creating function.

I don't want to say that this is impossible with R but I am not aware of how to do it. I am interested to see if other commentors can suggest a way.

Incidentally dot-to-access attribute syntax is mostly (entirely?) not available in r - usually you will use the `$` syntax, but that also won't work in this instance.