# In R, how to write a nested function that uses the arguments from the outer function?

Tags: r, function, nested, nested-function

```
f1<-function(x,y){
    f2<-function(a,b){
        print("f2")
        return(a+b)}
    f2(x,y)
    print("f1")
    return(x-y)}

f1(8,5)
```

I was trying above code to figure out the steps of operating function within function, so instead of writing two separate functions, I write the above code. But I can't get the output for `a+b` (which is `13`)

```
[1] "f2"
[1] "f1"
[1] 3
#[1] 13, this output is missing.
```

How should the code be corrected? Thank you.

*additional question: when I only write `x-y` instead of `return(x-y)` at the last line of the function `f1`, I got the same output. Is simply write `x-y` a bad practice or accpetable?

-------------------------Update:
I just find out a way to get all the four outputs by changing the 4th line from `return(a+b)` to `print(a+b)`
or to make it more simple, only use the `x`,`y`arguments:

```
f1<-function(x,y) {
    f2<-function() {
        print("f2")
        print(x+y)
        }
    f2()
    print("f1")
    x-y
    }
```

while I still don't understand why using `return(x+y)` or simply `x+y` at the 4th line could not get the output of `13`?

Comment: To omit the explicit `return` is a good R practice, in R the value of a function's last instruction is ts return value so there is no point in calling an extra function, `return`.

Comment: What happens is that you do not assign the value returned by `f2`. You call it and then move on to `x - y`, subtracting the input arguments. Remove `x-y` and put `f2(x, y)` in its place, after the `print("f1")`.

Comment: R functions return a single object to the environment where they were called. You cannot call `f1()` and get BOTH the object returned by `f2` and a different value returned by `f1()` separately. You can call `f2()` inside `f1()` and use the object returned by `f2()`. That "use" might include adding it to a `list` along with other objects and returning the list, e.g., you could have the last line of `f1` be `return(list(x - y, f2(x, y)))` -- or simply `list(x - y, f2(x, y))` for the same effect without using `return()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate, [Returning multiple objects in an R function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8936099/903061), though it's not clear if that's your goal - just a guess on my part for how you want your code "corrected". What is your goal?

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas! Sorry for unclear question, i would like to have all the 4 output
`[1] "f2"
[1] "f1"
[1] 3
[1] 13`
is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an expression is on a line by itself it will automatically print if you do it at the R console but that does not happen if it is within a function or within an expression.  Use `cat` or `print` for displaying.

To return two objects return a list containing both of them as shown at below.

The value of the last line that is run in a function is returned so you rarely need `return`.

```
f1a <- function(x, y) {
    f2 <- function(a, b) {
        print("f2")
        a + b
    }
    print("f1")
    list(x - y, f2(x, y))
}

result <- f1a(8, 5)
## [1] "f1"
## [1] "f2"

result[[1]]
## [1] 3
result[[2]]
## [1] 13

result
## [[1]]
## [1] 3
##
## [[2]]
## [1] 13
```

Other things we could do would be to replace the `list(...)` line in the code above with one of the following.  (The `c` versions would only be used if we knew that the arguments were always scalars.)

```
list(f1 = x - y, f2 = f2(x, y))       # named list
c(x - y, f2(x, y))                    # 2 element numeric vector
c(f1 = x - y, f2 = f2(x, y))          # 2 element named numeric vector
cbind(f1 = x - y, f2 = f2(x, y))      # matrix w column names
data.frame(f1 = x - y, f2 = f2(x, y)) # data.frame
```