# Returning Multiple Output Parameters from Optim

Tags: r

Im running an optimisation routine using optim in R and im telling the programme what i want returned. for example, if i put `return(op1$par)`, it will return all 4 of my variable values. Thats fine, and if i run `return(op1)`, I obviously get all the information from the optimisation routine (par, value, convergence etc). However, in this format, the par values arent accessible in the output, it simply details that there are 4 values.

Now what i need is to the get the parameter values and the convergence information at the same time. R wont let me call this  `return(op1$par, op1$convergence)` so im looking for the best way to get these two entities in one run?

I should specify that im writing this to a file for 1000s of iterations and not just looking to call it up once on screen.

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean that the par values are not accessible in the output if you return the `optim` result? Can't you assign `a <- fn(b)`, and then call `a$par`?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826519/function-returning-more-than-one-value?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
return(c(Parameters=op1$par, Convergence=op1$convergence))
```

The names `Parameters` and `Convergence` are only for identifying what are the parameters and what is the convergence, since this result will be a vector.

Answer (score 0):

By design, a function can return only one object (or else assignments like `a <- fn(b)` would get confusing; which thing do you assign?). But that object can be a vector, or a list (which is what `optim` does). So wrap your arguments in something like

```
return(c(par=op1$par, convergence=op1$convergence))
```

or more generally (for objects of different types),

```
return(list(par=op1$par, convergence=op1$convergence))
```