# Shiny - Source a R file,extract values and set input sliders according to the extracted values

Tags: r, shiny

Fresh to shiny...
 1. I want to create an `ui.R` using `dashboardPage` and define a `selectInput` box (Done!)
 2. As soon as the user will selects one of the fields in the `selectInput`, a `Schools_Info.R` file would be sourced.
    I have tried `source("Schools_Info.R")` but I want some function which will run `Schools_Info.R` in backgroud.
How you do that?
 3. `Schools_Info.R` contains values that I want to use as the `min` and `max` of a
`sliderInput`.
How can I define `sliderInput` that will adjust its limits(`min` and `max`) automatically according to whatever the user selects from `selectInput` box?

### ui.R

```
library(shiny)
options(shiny.trace=TRUE)
library(shinydashboard)

locations <- c("Select your location",
           paste0("\tLocation1"),
           paste0("\tLocation2"),               
           paste0("\tLocation3")
           )


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
    dashboardSidebar(
          selectInput("selectedLoc",choices = locations),
          source("Schools_Info.R"),
          sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, min, max)),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(

      box(
        title = "Controls",
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Try creating a file `global.R` and define the values

Comment: I've done some reading and it seems that this kind of application needs to be done  using `reactive programming` functions. Now, I'm at the point where the user can select a field from `selectInput` box but I do not know how to run a script from `shiny` server . Also, I need to pass the variable to that file as , based in the that variable, the script should return some constants .

Comment: to run a shiny app from the server you can do `runApp("~\nameofFolder")` .

Comment: no! I need to run a .R file not a shiny application

Comment: is there a function in your source file or does would it produce an output independently from the user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Schools_Info.R`, make sure you have functions defined.  Running that file should do nothing but define functions for later use.  Source `Schools_Info.R` at the beginning of `server.R`, even before `shinyServer(`.  Then have the functions run reactively using whatever the user picks from the `selectInput` widget.  You could have separate functions to grab the max and min values, or you could use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826519/function-returning-more-than-one-value/15140507#15140507) to return two values from a single function at the same time.  Then use [`updateSliderInput`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/updateSliderInput) to set the values of the min and max on the slider.

Schools_Info.r

```
GetMax = function(locality){15}
GetMin = function(locality){1}
```

server.R

```
max = reactive(GetMax(selectedLoc))
min = reactive(GetMax(selectedLoc))
observe({
  updateSliderInput(session, "slider", "Number of observations:", c(max, min))
)}
```

Obviously, I don't know what `Schools_Info.R` does, so the functions I put in are pretty trivial.  Also, I'm not totally clear on what `observe` does, so it might not be necessary.