# Function to create multiple lists in R

Tags: r, list

I'd like to be able to create a function that returns 3 lists. For instance:

```
Objects <- function(SetType, 2Type){
  1Set <- list()
  1Set$type <- SetType
  2Set <- list()
  2Set$type <- 2Type
  3Set <- list()

  return(1Set)
  return(2Set)
  return(3Set)
}
```

This only returns 1Set.

One option that I can think of is to create 2 functions that simply create 2Set and 3Set and then call upon them in the Objects function, but is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: do this `return(list(1Set,2Set,3Set))`

Comment: So simple, thank you!

Comment: Glad it help nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826519/how-to-assign-from-a-function-which-returns-more-than-one-value)

```
Objects <- function(SetType, 2Type){
  1Set <- list()
  1Set$type <- SetType
  2Set <- list()
  2Set$type <- 2Type
  3Set <- list()

  return(list(1Set,2Set,3Set))
}
Ret=Objects(SetType, 2Type)
1Set=Ret[[1]]
2Set=Ret[[2]]
3Set=Ret[[3]]
```